# Best practice to update the file header.php

Tags: templates, custom-header

I would like to know, what is the best practice for updating the `header.php` file:

From within WordPress editor: Appearance > Editor

**or** Directly in the `header.php` file itself (in the www_root)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question leans towards getting some subjective answers, as I think it's a matter of personal preference. The built-in editor works just as well as any other text editor. That goes for any of your theme files, not just `header.php`.

The benefit of using an external editor (like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and using [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) to FTP your changes), is that you have the possibility of using 'syntax coloring'.

I highly recommend Notepad++, as it supports multiple document encodings (UTF-8, ANSI, etc) and many scripting languages (with their generally accepted syntax coloring), such as PHP, JavaScript and CSS, your most common languages when working with WordPress.

Comment: +1 for having the same infrastructure and work flow as I do. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i do actually user Notepad++, great editor. Appreciate the tip

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I never edit using the built-in editor. If you make one PHP mistake and hit the `save` button, your site will crash and you won't be able to correct your mistake. You'll then have to use FTP or equivalent to modify the file.